# Как найти totalPages находящийся в элементе используя bs4

Tags: python, html, bs4

Вёрстка:

```
<body>
 32123112342342423
  <div class="filterBlock">
   <b>
    Сортировка
   </b>
   : артикул
   <img class="remove" code="sort" src="/ii/remove2.png" title="Убрать фильтр">
  </div>
  ","firstProduct":1,"lastProduct":24,"currentPage":1,"totalPages":283,"totalProducts":6789,"filters":[{"code":"ikid","ids":[1,2,3,4,5]},{"code":"cid","ids":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11,12,13,20,22,32,39,44]},{"code":"scid","ids":[1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,12,13,14,16,19,20,21,22,23,27,28,29,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,40,41,42,45,46,47,48,50,51,53,54,56,58,59,60,62,65,67,69,74,75,76,78,82,83,84]},{"code":"icid","ids":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17,18,19,20,26,27,28,31,32]},{"code":"avid","ids":[5,6,7]},{"code":"coid","ids":[0,3,4,6,7,13,14,15,17,22,23,25,27,29,33,36,40,48,49,50,53,54,56,57,59,60,64,65,69,72,73,74,78,83,84,88,90,91,92,93,95,96,97,98,99,102,103,107,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,118,119,121,122,123,124,125,127,130,131]},{"code":"selid","ids":[0,1]},{"code":"grid","ids":[3,5,6,7]},{"code":"mid","ids":[2,3]},{"code":"shp","ids":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,14,17,23]},{"code":"iid","ids":[1,3,4,5,6,7,10,35,36,37,39,40,42,57,61,65,75,83,84,85,94,96,97,99,100,101,103,104,105,106,113,116,119,124,138,140,142,145,149,152,158,160,162,165,166,168,171,172,173,177,178,180,182,186,189,190,196]},{"code":"mcid","ids":[0]},{"code":"mfid","ids":[0,1,2]}]}
 
</body>
```

Мне нужно достать totalPages который находится не в элементе. Использовать bs4.

Comment: Непонятно, что именно вы хотите достать, напишите явный пример в вопросе

Comment: Мне надо найти  ","firstProduct":1,"lastProduct":24,"currentPage":1,"totalPages": и продолжение

Comment: Вот зуб даю не так тег в реале выглядит. А вот та часть которую вы вытащить пытаетесь в тег script часом не завернута?

Comment: Да нет. Вообще мне надо вытащить от туда totalPages

Comment: А если ещё точнее то это не страница, а пост запрос который даёт данные в виде того что я прислал, только это малая часть

Comment: Если код реально как вы его здесь представили, не насилуйте bs4 и свою голову. Бахнете по нему регехр'ом

Comment: Судя по ответам и комментариям вы скрыли от всех что у вас json и его поле получить гораздо проще чем в описаном вами случае

Comment: Это да я просто сам не понимал что это json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rep = requests.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data).json()
first = rep["firstProduct"]
last = rep["lastProduct"]
current_Page = rep['currentPage']
total_pages = rep['totalPages']
soup = BeautifulSoup(rep['productsHtml'], 'lxml')
```

Comment: А вы случайно не знаете почему раставлены обратные слэши на странице к которой идёт post запрос, это json чтоли? {"productsHtml":"<div class=\"products\">\r\n  <div class=\"item wide\">\r\n    <div class=\"image\">\r\n      <div class=\"icons\"><img src=\"/ii/iconInCart.png\" title=\"Уже в корзине\" class=\"iconInCart\" style=\"display:block;\"><img src=\"/ii/iconDisabled.png\" title=\"Снято с производства\"><img class=\"favtoggle\.

Comment: это json чтоли? Да, через пост запрос передается json. "почему раставлены обратные слэши на странице" скорее всего как и в пайтоне выполняют экранирование спец символов. Ну и заодно ответ обновил.

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

body = soup.find('body').text
a = body.split('currentPage')[-1]
print(a.split(',')[1].split(':')[1])
```

Мы разделяем на два элемента `a = body.split('currentPage')[-1]`, после делим на , выбираем 1 объект и дальше достаём значение

Comment: Асоциативно выглядит как будто взяли скальпель и отрезали им сочный стейк.

Comment: Я просто не знаю как по другому это сделать

Comment: Если присмотрется явно прослеживается структура  JSON.. В примере код не полный c нарушенной структурой.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]